# Cannot open google map inside the window in Angular, Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to open a google map in a new window. Here I want to keep google map height and width as 200px and need to add help text top of the map.

**place.component.html file**

`<button (click)="openGoogleMap()">open new window!</button>`

**place.component.ts file**

```
openGoogleMap() {
    const mapUrl = `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${encodeURIComponent(this.placeModel.detail)}`;
    const windowFeatures = 'height=300,width=400,top=100,left=100';
  
    const mapWindow = window.open('', '_blank', windowFeatures);
  
    if (mapWindow) {
      const helpText = 'Right-click on the map to copy latitude and longitude.';
      
      const paragraph = this.renderer.createElement('p');
      const text = this.renderer.createText(helpText);
      this.renderer.appendChild(paragraph, text);
      this.renderer.appendChild(mapWindow.document.body, paragraph);
  
      const iframe = this.renderer.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.src = mapUrl;
      iframe.width = '100%';
      iframe.height = '200px';
      mapWindow.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    } else {
      console.error('Unable to open Google Maps window');
    }
  }
```

when I tried to I got like this. Here I don't want to keep window height and width as 200px. I want to keep map height and width as 200px and need to add help text top of the map.

[google map error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkKLD.png).

here I want to open,

1. google map.
2. instead of open new window can I do same this opening new tab in same browser.

Please someone can help met. Thank you